# javascript set a value equal to the result of a function to re-use that value. how to avoid having that function called each time the value is used?

Tags: javascript

I've got a variable defined that is equal to the result of some method, and I am exporting and using it in a few of my components.

In my helper, I have something like:

`export const myValue = someFunction()`

In the component, I do something like this:

`import { myValue } from '../helpers';`

Then use that value.

Unfortunately, each time I use `myValue`, it calls that function but is there a way I can call the function just once so I can use the result everywhere without having to run the method?

How can I do this?  The function whose result I am using is a heavy check that has to iterate over all elements but this number can vary.

Comment: "each time I use myValue, it calls that function " what makes you believe that?

Comment: I assume you mean you're doing `import {myValue}...` multiple times?

Comment: I'm using myValue in a react component that's iterating over a list of results and myValue is used for one of the fields.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your syntax about so forgive me if this is totally wrong, but can't you do:

export const myValue = myValue || someFunction()

Comment: Further to Liora’s point, according to the ES6 spec, the contents of the module shouldn’t be getting re-run after the first evaluation. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-module-records

Comment: Can you post some more of the source code of your shared module and some of the code that’s calling it?